# empty lines outside of method body with intellij getter/setter templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my current company we use a somewhat different code style. Between methods there is a divider consisting of a new line, some slashes, another newline to structure the code.
I wanted to adapt the IntelliJ getter/setter templates to auto-generate these.

This is the default:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

When I just try to add the new lines and the slashes:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))

//////////

#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

I get an `incorrect method` error. Without the new lines it is working great. Any ideas on how I can change the template to achieve my goal?

Comment: Instead of empty line try use this: `#set($emptyLine = '')
${emptyLine}`

Comment: That causes the same issue for me. I fear it has something to do with the way the private/public-Modifier gets inserted by IntelliJ, but I am not sure.

Comment: I can't check now, so I'll answer later if you still need help

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an answer, because it will be quite detailed and will not fit into the comment.

If the reasons are not interesting, then just skip to the end, to the section with the solution.

At first, I used that snippet, as i mentioned in comments:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#set($newline = "
")
${newline}//////////////////${newline}
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Well, it didn't really work, so first I looked at the documentation. According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html?_ga=2.266567054.1457457269.1596438673-951998056.1595524527&_gac=1.113299573.1596479703.Cj0KCQjw6575BRCQARIsAMp-ksPMPlVAQRhIzSN8wDVIw5llRsSDk4vF82menfS97G4X2pHkBBkoKP4aArXeEALw_wcB&_gl=1%2A1lbwmpy%2A_gcl_aw%2AR0NMLjE1OTY0Nzk3MDIuQ2owS0NRanc2NTc1QlJDUUFSSXNBTXAta3NQTVBsVkFRUmhJelNOOHdEVkl3NWxsUnNTRGs0dkY4Mm1lbmZTOTdHNFgycEhrQkJrb0tQNGFBclhlRUFMd193Y0I.#customize-templates), IntelliJ use [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html) as template engine. And given its syntax, everything should be handled okay. And it is so, if you look at the error message:

[image: error]

you can see that it handles indentation correctly.

So, I looked into the source to see [how they handle it](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/6ccc4f3231aecfec010afe55084d210d14e508b7/java/java-psi-impl/src/com/intellij/psi/impl/PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.java#L185), and it turned out that they also [use the language server for validation](https://github.com/consulo/consulo/blob/c8591d684e19eb3797d83b5eefb48c4801d74a23/modules/base/core-impl/src/main/java/com/intellij/psi/impl/source/DummyHolder.java#L67). Why they consider the beginning of the method with an empty line to be invalid idk, it's enough for me.

**So, solution**:

Use default snippet, but create live template (yes, live template support blank lines).

So, create template, like this:

[image: example-template]

Select whole method body (I prefer `Ctrl + W`, when cursor inside method body). And then `Ctrl+Alt+J -> template_name`

More info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-custom-code-constructs-using-live-templates.html?_ga=2.266567054.1457457269.1596438673-951998056.1595524527&_gac=1.113299573.1596479703.Cj0KCQjw6575BRCQARIsAMp-ksPMPlVAQRhIzSN8wDVIw5llRsSDk4vF82menfS97G4X2pHkBBkoKP4aArXeEALw_wcB&_gl=1%2A1lbwmpy%2A_gcl_aw%2AR0NMLjE1OTY0Nzk3MDIuQ2owS0NRanc2NTc1QlJDUUFSSXNBTXAta3NQTVBsVkFRUmhJelNOOHdEVkl3NWxsUnNTRGs0dkY4Mm1lbmZTOTdHNFgycEhrQkJrb0tQNGFBclhlRUFMd193Y0I.#surround-a-block-of-code-with-a-live-template).

Comment: This way I can only add one getter/setter at at time and surround it with the extra steps. I don't save enough keystrokes then ;-).

Comment: Well, probably here (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) you can get a better way to do this

Comment: I created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247476 as an issue. Thank you for your help though :-).